# mypy can't find my package when it is installed

Tags: mypy

I would like to use mypy for type checking my package.

Here is my directory structure:

```
my_dir/
    setup.py
    src/
        packme/
            __init__.py
            Packman.py
            PackerTemplate.py
```

if I do:

```
cd src
mypy packme
```

Everything works fine in the sense that I get `mypy` warning and error messages about bad types and so on.

However, if I do:

```
cd my_dir
pip install .
mypy -p packme
```

I get `Can't find package 'packme'`. I tried to generate the `stub` files with `stubgen` put them in say `my_dir/stubs` directory and make the `MYPYPATH` envvar point to this directory but this still does not work.

Would you have any idea about what I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I could finally find the reason for my problem. My stubs directory was not reflecting my source directory structure. Doing that solved the problem.